# How to add order by dropdown to woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sql-order-by

I am using a custom theme for a custom Woocommerce site. I have copied default woocommerce orderby *class* file to my custom theme's loop directory.

I am trying to display the sort by dropdown in a widget, but no luck.

[woocommerce_catalog_ordering] shortcode does not seem to produce anything, even if placed in a page as a block.

What is missing?

Comment: Try `echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_catalog_ordering]');`

Comment: Thanks @AndyTschiersch, no luck

Comment: Where do you place this code?

Comment: @AndyTschiersch in orderby.php class of course.. also adding this to functions.php as an action does not yield anything at all, also tried many hooks (before-after product etc)

Comment: orderby.php is not a class, it is a template. This template will be loaded by woocommerce at a certain time, you can not use it to display the "sort by dropdown" in a widget. You can try to create a [custom widget](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/) an use the code from orderby.php in it.

Comment: @AndyTschiersch you are right, why did I write class instead of file.. Anyway, adding this as a shortcode to functions.php also does not bring anything.. There must be some missing functionality here and there, but what?

Comment: It is difficult to help without any code that you tried.